# Redis DB with Jmeter Integration - Can not Connect

Tags: redis, jmeter

I have a question about connecting Redis DB to Jmeter, using jp@gc - Redis Data Set.

I created a test and want to see a value from Redis, the problem is that When I add the Redis DB component nothing happened, I press the Play button and nothing happened.

I think I am not configured the Redis as expected in jmeter.
I didnt create any variable just name a new variable called dsos.

I just want to pass the value from redis of dsos_13_173 to the parameter dsos
1. How can I see why the configuration not succeed?
2. What I am missing?

I am using jmeter 3.2, with plugin v0.2 and installed it from plug in manager, and the DB is remote I am using IP not localhost as in **all** examples

Regards

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Redis Data Set config acts alike [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), so given you want to use the data from Redis in i.e. [HTTP Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) you just need to refer to it as `${dsos}` where required.

You can also double check the associated JMeter Variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

See [JMeter’s Redis Data Set - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) for comprehensive explanation, step-by-step instruction and example test plan.

Comment: Hey @Dimitri, the problem I am facing is before everything, I can not connect to the redis via jmeter.  I just created redis data set call, I used jmeter 3.2. and just jmeter not connect to redis, I added a new Pic, and in the debug sampler evrything is empty, can you please advise how to investigate this issue? regards

Comment: Is this plugin ever worked with IP and not with Local DB? is this plug in valid for 3.2 jmeter's version?